# How to exclude from foreach an array that does not contain an object?

Tags: node.js

I'm receiving an array and performing a treatment to extract some information.

When I get the matrix like this, everything goes well!

```
[
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  }
]
```

But when the array comes like this:

```
[
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  { averages: 'No data in period.' }
]
```

I get this error:

> ccs.medias.forEach is not a function

Could this be the error?

> { averages: 'No data in period.' }

The code mentioned to filter the information I want is this:

```
    function test(arr) {
        let results = [];
        arr.forEach(ccs => {
          ccs.medias.forEach(element => {
            if (element["TYPE"] === 'AAA') {
              results.push(element["STATUS"])
            }
          })
        })
        return results;
    }
```

As I mentioned above, this code works for the first array example, but not for the following one.
I appreciate if anyone can help me analyze it!

Comment: Just check if it's an array before you treat it as one. `if( !(ccs.medias instanceof Array) ) return;`

Comment: This question is tagged as "mongodb", what is the mongo part? Filter the non-array values in the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you guessed right, problem is here:

```js
{ averages: 'No data in period.' }
```

Before using [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), you need to make sure property value (`ccs.averages`) is `array`, so just add simple if-condition like:

```js
if (Array.isArray(ccs.averages)) {
  // Do what you need with array and only
}
```

Full code:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  {
    averages: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  },
  { averages: 'No data in period.' }
]

function test(arr) {
  let results = [];
  arr.forEach(ccs => {
    // Make sure .avarages is array
    if (Array.isArray(ccs.averages)) {
      ccs.averages.forEach(element => {
      if (element["TYPE"] === 'AAA') {
        results.push(element["STATUS"])
      }
    })
    }
  })
  return results;
}

console.log(test(arr));
```

Refs: [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Answer (score 0):

As this question is tagged as "mongo", to do it in a query and retrieve results directly without the fields which are not an array you can use one of these queries:

For a `find` query you can add:

```
"averages": { "$type": "array }
```

Like this:

```
db.collection.find({
  "averages": {
    "$type": "array"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MGz2o_9rV8P)

Also if you are using an aggregation stage you can add a `$match` stage like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "averages": {
        "$type": "array"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f1BkzFVk_IA)

Note that the queries use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

In this way you can avoid the loop.